# Which electrode configuration should have the highest electric field produced?

Tags: high-voltage, electrode, electric-field

I'm currently simulating the the electric field produced by different types of electrodes.

The electric field is observed on the insulator that is sandwiched between 2 electrodes, one being 10 kV whereas the other one is 0 kV. The electrode configuration that I'm currently simulating is:-

- Needle to needle
- Needle to sphere
- Sphere to sphere

In theory, the electric field should be the strongest at a pointy conductor (needle in my case) thus it should be the needle to needle configuration, right? In the simulation, the highest value that I obtained was for needle to sphere. Is this theoretically correct or is there something wrong with my simulation?

I'm simulating using Quickfield 6.6 student version.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, instead of electrodes at 0 and 10 kV, electrodes at +5 kV and -5 kV. It's the same field, it just makes the next bit easier to think about.

Where will the 0 V equipotential plane be between the two electrodes?

For like electrode shapes, it will obviously be in the geometric middle.

Where will it be for the needle/sphere case?

It won't be in the middle, but will be offset.

Which way will it be offset?

Being wider, the sphere electrode will have 'more influence' than the needle electrode on the potentials in the middle, so will push the 0 V equipotential closer to the needle. This increases the field gradient in the vicinity of the needle tip.